# protobuf webhook with no fixed request structure

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, proto3, github-webhook

I am using `Golang` as my backend and `proto3` as my API definitions. I have `grpc-gateway` to support http along with grpc.

My use case is To have a webhook API which gets in some payload and processes it. I don't have control over the client and nor do i have surety about the payload structure.

How do i define my Request object?

example :

```
service RepoService {
  rpc PostGitPR(PostGitPREventRequest) returns (PostGitPREventResponse) {
    option (google.api.http) = {
      post: "/git/pr/event"
      body: "*"
    };
  }
```

Do i use `any.proto` or `[]byte`? I am not sure both will work.

Answer (score 1):

If it's impossible to predict a payload you can use `google.api.HttpBody` as your request object in the proto file. See this: https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/api/httpbody.proto